# Do I have a 64 bit PC?

Tags: windows, memory, motherboard, 32-vs-64-bit

I am trying to find out if this bad computer of mine is 64 bit. I have a 32 bit and want to get more than 4 GB of ram. I have 2 GB and I can survive 2017 with it. But I want to upgrade to 8 GB. Here's the "systeminfo" command results. Can I put 64 bit Windows on this?

> Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.15063]
>   (c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> Loading Hotfix Information ...
>
> Host Name:                 SAT-L350
>
> OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Home
>
> OS Version:                10.0.15063 N/A Build 15063
>
> OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
>
> OS Configuration:          Standalone Workstation
>
> OS Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free
>
> Registered Owner:          Admin
>
> Registered Organization:
>
> Product ID:                *Censored*
>
> Original Install Date:     *Censored
>
> System Boot Time:          *Censored*
>
> System Manufacturer:       TOSHIBA
>
> System Model:              Satellite L350
>
> System Type:               X86-based PC
>
> Processor(s):              1 Processor(s) Installed.
>                              [01]: x64 Family 6 Model 15 Stepping 13 GenuineIntel ~2000 Mhz
>
> BIOS Version:              INSYDE 1.20, 28/08/2008
>
> Windows Directory:         C:\WINDOWS
>
> System Directory:          C:\WINDOWS\system32
>
> Boot Device:               \Device\HarddiskVolume1
>
> System Locale:             en-gb;English (United Kingdom)
>
> Input Locale:              en-gb;English (United Kingdom)
>
> Time Zone:                 *Censored*
>
> Total Physical Memory:     1,916 MB
>
> Available Physical Memory: 513 MB
>
> Virtual Memory: Max Size:  6,012 MB
>
> Virtual Memory: Available: 3,676 MB
>
> Virtual Memory: In Use:    2,336 MB
>
> Page File Location(s):     C:\pagefile.sys
>
> Domain:                    WORKGROUP
>
> Logon Server:              \SAT-L350
>
> Hotfix(s):                 5 Hotfix(s) Installed.
>                              [01]: KB4021572
>                              [02]: KB4022405
>                              [03]: KB4025376
>                              [04]: KB4038806
>                              [05]: KB4038788
>
> Network Card(s):           2 NIC(s) Installed.
>                              [01]: Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller
>                                    Connection Name: Local Area Connection
>                                    Status:          Media disconnected
>                              [02]: Realtek RTL8187B Wireless 802.11b/g 54Mbps USB 2.0 Network Adapter
>                                    Connection Name: Wireless Network Connection
>                                    DHCP Enabled:    Yes
>                                    DHCP Server:     *Censored*
>                                    IP address(es)
>                                    [01]: *Censored* 
>                                    [02]: *Censored*
>
> Hyper-V Requirements:      VM Monitor Mode Extensions: No
>                              Virtualization Enabled In Firmware: No
>                              Second Level Address Translation: No
>                              Data Execution Prevention Available: Yes

Comment: Your mainboard needs to support 8GB of RAM. You can find out which mainboard you have with this command `wmic baseboard get product,manufacturer`

Comment: Your product ID and OS install date literally don't identify you (no, "product ID" is not your Windows serial key)- why did you bother censoring that?

Comment: @cybermonkey because you can calculate the serial based on the digital product is. [See this post](https://superuser.com/a/1247859/390654$)

Comment: If you go to the website of most reputable sellers of RAM, they have an app which will diagnose what options are available for your computer. Unless you have done some seriously "non-standard" mods to your hardware, these are going to be accurate - after all, the company doesn't want the hassle of selling you something that doesn't work and having to deal with you returning it for a refund!

Comment: Welcome on SuperUser...  in future try to do one question for post. Take some moment to read [ask], it will help people to answer you more properly and to save time... Do not forget to show some effort more searching on internet too (and showing the results) and filtering part of the information not essential (even if it could be difficult). Maybe even for this you had till now 4+ and 4-...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this is probably your machine. Worth taking a look at the bottom of the laptop and confirming the exact model number though.

http://www.toshiba.co.uk/discontinued-products/satellite-l350-170/

The good news is that you should be able to run a 64-bit OS on that thing.

The bad news is that at least according to Toshiba you can install a maximum of 4GB of ram. On the bright side it seems your laptop has a new enough chipset* to actually use all 4GB (unlike slightly older laptops that could only use 3.something GB).

Sometimes manufactures do under-state the maximum ram but my googling isn't turning up anything much. I expect the only way to find out if 8GB will work is to try it and 8GB (2x4GB) of DDR2 is pretty expensive.

* The specs don't say what chip-set it has but they do say it has a GMA 4500M which from some googling appears to indicate a "Monetevideo" chip-set. Afaict Santa rosa (Monetevideo's predecessor) was the first Intel mobile chipset to support the full 4GB.

Comment: Memory maker Crucial has maintained a memory upgrade database for a number of years that can take the trial and error out of attempting to install a larger than officially rated memory stick.  Unfortunately, having looked up the model you identified it's limited to 4GB.  http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/Toshiba/satellite-l350-170

Comment: In my experiance crucial show the manufacturers official maximum, not the (sometimes higher) actual maximum.

Answer (score 7):

Is your PC 64-bit? Yes.

> Processor(s): 1 Processor(s) Installed. [01]: x64 Family 6 Model 15
>   Stepping 13 GenuineIntel ~2000 Mhz

This is really the only part of all the information you’ve dumped that is relevant. `x64` indicates the CPU uses the 64-bit assembly/instruction set.

Comment: Specifically, this indicates that he has a [Merom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merom_(microprocessor)) mobile CPU, branded as a "Core 2 Duo". Those have the x86-64 extensions, which Intel calls Intel 64 and AMD calls AMD64. x64 is the way Microsoft writes it.

Answer (score 3):

You have a 64 bit cpu but it looks like your laptop is only capable of having 4 GB RAM installed (2x2GB). You'll need to double check that information and the type of memory you need for that laptop.

Answer (score 1):

### *Do have I a **64** bit**s** pc?*

**Yes you have**, it is written in the line with the word **"Processor(s)"** inside `:-)`

> Processor(s): 1 Processor(s) Installed. [01]: **x64** Family 6 Model 15 Stepping 13 GenuineIntel ~2000 Mhz

- This is the question you should really had asked for: "**Which model is it?**"
  You should do some research from yourself, more than the windows output

  1. It was probably written on some stickers on your computer (if they are  not removed), it may appear when the computer starts on the black screen before the OS is loaded.
  2. You may enter in the bios (that you may ask to upgrade<sup>[[1b](http://support.toshiba.com/support/viewContentDetail?contentId=4003679)]</sup>) and probably easily read it.
  3. You may install a program to help you, such as the [Intel® Processor Identification Utility](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/processors/000005651.html)<sup>[[1](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/processors/000005651.html)]</sup> or [cpu-z](https://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html)<sup>[[2](https://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html)]</sup>.
  4. You may rely on internet <sup>[[3](https://milkyway.cs.rpi.edu/milkyway/cpu_list.php)]</sup> and discover that is supported by  `LGA775` (the first below) or by the sockets `PBGA479`, `PPGA478` the second one.

     > Intel(R) Pentium(R) Dual CPU [E2180](https://ark.intel.com/en/products/31733/Intel-Pentium-Processor-E2180-1M-Cache-2_00-GHz-800-MHz-FSB) @ 2.00GHz [Family 6 Model 15 Stepping 13]
     >   or
     >   Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU [T7250](https://ark.intel.com/en/products/31728/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-T7250-2M-Cache-2_00-GHz-800-MHz-FSB) @ 2.00GHz [Family 6 Model 15 Stepping 13]
  5. You can go to the Intel site and download the specifications of the whole family 6 from the page ["6th Generation Intel® Processor Family"](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/processors/000005651.html)<sup>[[4](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/processors/000005651.html)]</sup>

### *I want to **upgrade to 8 GB**.*

Well you can install a 64 bit system but to know if you can address 8GB **you have to check the motherboard** not the CPU (even because you need to know the type supported). You know that

> System Manufacturer: TOSHIBA
>   System Model: Satellite L350

What it misses is the [sub-model](https://www.mrmemory.co.uk/memory-ram-upgrades/toshiba/satellite/l350-series) <sup>[[5](https://www.mrmemory.co.uk/memory-ram-upgrades/toshiba/satellite/l350-series)]</sup>: for example the *Toshiba Satellite L350-00J* holds up to 4 GB instead the *L350-ST3702* holds up to 8 GB. On that site are reported more then 3 pages of *sub-codes* this is not something that we can do for you...

... but it is even reported <sup>[[6](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/identify-model-toshiba-laptop-51000.html)]</sup> that you can find your full model number... flipping it!

> 1. Flip your Toshiba laptop over and locate the sticker on the back of the case. Note the number next to "Model No.," "Part No." or "Satellite." This is the model-part number.
> 2. Power on the Toshiba laptop. Click the "Start" button on your desktop, and then right-click "Computer." Click "Properties." The model number may appear in the Properties

Or you can open a *dos window* (`cmd.exe`) and ask inside <sup>[[7](https://www.howtogeek.com/208420/how-to-check-your-motherboard-model-number-on-your-windows-pc/)]</sup>

```
wmic baseboard get product,manufacturer
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes Its capable to run 64 bit OS, 
You can use a miximum o f 4 gb of RAM,
You wanted 8 gb RAM but you can focus on a SSD which will be the most significant factor.

Comment: Sorry for being so late. This thread has already got loads of answers in only a week. Thanks guys.

Comment: Oh, and I will get an SSD soon. My machine isn't that good, but 4 GB of ram will do the job fine. I also tried to answer Hastur's question, but ended up with this:

Comment: Oh, and I will get an SSD soon. My machine isn't that good, but 4 GB of ram will do the job fine. I also tried to answer Hastur's question, but ended up with this: https://imgur.com/a/kxe41

Comment: Glad that it helped, you can up vote this answer if it helped you in some way.